# Analyze/RE device through usb ports

Tags: usb

[image: pins layout]
Hi, I disassembled my old smart TV and found the wifi card pretty interesting.
On the internet i found a minimal manaual datasheet...
It was simple to recognise that there is usb pins layout on there and I am trying to see what information I can get from only connecting it to my computer.

If I'm right and pins 1-4 are usb , I have a few questions:

1. why does it say the vcc (pin 1) is 3.3v? When I connect it to the usb port of my computer it immediately gets 5v from it, no? Should i do something about that?
2. Would it be bad guess to try only connect pins 1-4 to the computer? I mean - should I also connect pins 6 and 8? (The "none usb" gnd+vcc ports).
   More generally, what is a good guess of the 8 pins functioning? (Like what are the usb pins and does the usb-vcc is the only source of voltage)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it's 3.3V, you would need a level shift (eg make 5V signal to 3V3 and 3V3 to 5V). Also, you don't know if the TV is usb host or usb slave. Maybe this port is for plugging other slave devices to?